# Cannot access wamp phpmyadmin after changing root password..?

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

i just installed wamp and changed the password of root but i cant access phpmyadmin.

it says.

```
phpMySql Error – Access denied for user ‘root’@localhost’ (using password: YES)
```

I tried some solutions from google nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the login credentials in config.inc.php in "C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.4.5". (i.e., change the password from '' to "" )